# inflate and binding issue, inflate option is not available and only option for binding:InputBinding

Tags: java, kotlin, authentication, build.gradle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WjDm.png)
I have tried to solve this by using different patterns but I don't know exactly what to do.
In buildgradle.kt also there is no andriod{
}   function given .in place of binding:ActivityLoginBinding  there is option of binding:InputBinding and LoginActivityBingding
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBjTO.png)

Answer (score 0):

First, Kindly add following things into the app level build.gradle file if you haven't mentioned it yet.

```
android {
...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

And second thing is like that you have to follow pattern as per the name of the xml file:
Ex. if xml file name is like activity_main. So in your case the binding will be like:

```
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

if you still face any error then kindly read the bellow doc to learn further. [ViewBinding Documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)